# How can I show a divider before first action item in Action Bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How can I show a divider before first and after last action item in Action Bar?

Normal behavior: `ACTION1 | ACTION2`

I want: `| ACTION1 | ACTION2 |`

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to do this is to use custom action layouts that would include the appropriate dividers.